# Get return value of AWS getSignedUrl function within a seperate function with callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, callback, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a  function to get a signedurl for s3 in a seperate javascript file(s3.js). Now I need to call that function in my route, placed in another file.
getSignedUrl works and I was able to log the result correctly. But it doesn't pass result to the caller function.

get signed url function (s3.js file)

```
 getPreSignedurl: function(filekey,callback) {

        const bucket = 'bucket-name'
        const key = filekey
        const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5
        s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key,
            Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
        }, function(err, url) {
            if (err) return err
            else {
                console.log(url); //url prints perfectly 
                callback(url);
            }
        })
    }
```

above function works correctly and log the url, but it doesn't pass url to the caller function.
Caller function looks like this

```
var S3 = require("./s3");

router.post('/get_prifile_pic_upload_presigned_url', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), authRole, function(req,res, next) {
     S3.getPreSignedurl(req.body.filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return (err);
        else {
            //cannot get url from here
            return res.json({
               success: true,
               msg: 'presigned',
               obj:data
            });
        }
     });
 });
```

I cannot get the signed inside url from this function. can anyone hep me on this?

Comment: `callback(url);` should be `callback(null, url);`.  Your callback expects *two ordered values:* **err, data** ... so, as written, you are setting err to the url and data is undefined.  Basic programming, unrelated to S3.